# How to get this below output from DUAL in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
1         L            R

1         1            1 
1         1            2
1         1            3
1         2            1
1         2            2
1         2            3
1         3            1
1         3            2
1         3            3
```

Using this query but not able to get for L column

```
Select 1,level R
from DUAL
Connect by level <=3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a **Cartesian join** in the **row generator** query you have to generate `3 rows`. Thus, the **Cartesian product** would generate total `9 rows`.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT LEVEL rn FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=3
  3    )
  4  SELECT 1, A.rn L, b.rn R FROM DATA A, DATA b
  5  /

         1          L          R
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         1          1          2
         1          1          3
         1          2          1
         1          2          2
         1          2          3
         1          3          1
         1          3          2
         1          3          3

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 1, L, R
  from (Select level R
          from DUAL
       Connect by level <=3),
       (Select level L
          from DUAL
       Connect by level <=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT 1, CEIL(lvl/3) AS l
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CEIL(lvl/3) ORDER BY lvl ) AS r
  FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL AS lvl FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9
);
```

The above avoids a cartesian join. [**See SQLFiddle here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/1721)